# angular ng serve application reloads few times in chrome. Why?

Tags: angularjs, angular, google-chrome

Hi I want to setup development environment for Angular like described here:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I did project setup and when I run

```
ng serve
```

application is available in browser (both Chrome and Firefox) on http://localhost:4200/. But something strange happen with Chrome. When I save edited project file (in my case app.component.ts), page should reload itself, and this happen in both browsers, but **in Chrome it subsequently reloads few times** (2, 5, 10 ... looks random) and **I cannot get why?**

Software I use:

- Ubuntu 16.04.
- Node is latest stable v6.11.4.
- Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I tried with IDE and with simple text editor - this happen with both, so I was able to track down this a Chrome browser or some Angular (or dependencies) issue. **Should I resolve or live with Firefox is fine?**

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, there is an active bug report thread on this same topic: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8195

Comment: Right. I did this bug report and as you can see, it is not resolved yet. Chrome is better for development, and Firefox not an option, as it not provides convenient way to debug. For some last time I see this happen less then before. Probably to fix it needs to update software to latest. Sorry we not have any proven solution on that.